# Only one user at once through remote

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

This is probably an easy question for anyone used to servers, and I know I once managed to do it, but I don't remember how.

I purchased a VPS and am able to connect correctly as Administrator, and can start, let's say, MyServer.exe. Problem is, if I connect as Administrator on another device, this process is still there, but I can't see it.

What I want to do is limit the connection per user to 1, and disconnect others when one logs in. I know there was a simpler term, a simple way, but I truly don't remember. And since I'm not used to the vocabulary of servers, I couldn't find it in the S/F questions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for doing this:

- Limit users to a single session using group policy. This will only allow one session per user and so attempt to reconnect to any disconnected sessions. Follow the steps in 
  [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787315%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to enable it.
- Connect to the physical console session. In Server 2003 you can connect to the physical console session using the /admin switch (or /console in older RDP clients). This is not the same in server 2008. To connect to the console open the RDP client from the run box with the following command:

  ```
  Mstsc /v < ip or name of server > /admin
  ```

Comment: THanks, the group policy restriction was exactly what I wanted.